# Como ler arquivos MFD impressora fiscal do disco rígido

Tags: c#, vb.net

Existe alguma forma de ler arquivos MFD impressora fiscal que esta no disco rígido?

Esses arquivos são binarios existe alguma forma de ler arquivos binários e salvar com txt?

*Impressora*: BEMATECH MP-2100 FI

Comment: Qual Marca e Modelo da Impressora?

Comment: BEMATECH MP-2100

Comment: @JoandreiyCordeiro possivelmente na `dll` que a bematech disponibiliza deve existir um método que faça essa conversão, só dar uma procurada no site http://partners.bematech.com.br/suporte-recursos/help-online/

Answer (score 3):

**Caso não queira desenvolver esta solução siga este tutorial:**
[Capturando a MFD e gerando o espelho dos documentos pelo WINMFD2](http://partners.bematech.com.br/2012/06/edicao-123-capturando-a-mfd-e-gerando-o-espelho-dos-documentos-pelo-winmfd2)

[image: Retorno da leitura MFD]

**Download da ferramenta:**
[Instalador WinMFD2](http://partners.bematech.com.br/suporte-recursos/downloads/?did=105)

**Tutorial Resumido:**

1. Selecionar o arquivo de origem (arquivo .MFD);
2. Selecionar o arquivo de destino;
3. Tipo de relatório, sendo as opções os formatos:

   - Arquivo de Texto (*.txt);
   - Arquivo de Texto Formatado (*.rtf);
   - Arquivo de Dados (*.mdb); ou
   - Arquivo XML (*.xml).
4. Tipo de Download:

   - Total
   - Por Data
   - Por COO (Contador de Ordem de Operação)

**Caso queira desenvolver uma solução própria:**

Utilize o [ACBrFramework](http://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/index.php?/forum/41-net-c-e-vbnet/), um Interop do já conhecido projeto ACBr. Este framework encapsula diversas operações com várias impressoras fiscais. Código fonte e exemplos disponível para C#, VB.NET, etc: [Aqui](http://acbrframework.sourceforge.net/downloads/codigo-fonte/)